# Android 7.0 Nougat picks up default strings when device language is en_US

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-resources, android-7.0-nougat

As per the documentation in [Language and Locale](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) there have been improvements to Resource-Resolution Strategy from Android 7.0(API level 24) which is easy to understand with the following table:
[Improved Resource-Resolution strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LQbA.png)

As per my requirements, I want my app's default langauge to be en_US. So, I am not providing separate resources for en_US. I also have en_GB resources present separately.

Now, as per the resolution strategy, if my device's language is en_US then the order in which it should look for resources is en_US -> en -> en_GB -> default which means for all locales of en, in my case en_GB will be picked up as I don't have 'en' resource separately, but the child 'en_GB' is present.

But, when I select my device language to be en_US, it correctly picks up the default language(en_US in my case) and not en_GB, which is exactly what I need in case the device language is en_US. When some other locale like en_IN or en_AU is selected, it picks up en_GB.

One way to solve this is that I provide en_US strings in 'en' and en_GB separately, which would lead to my desired behaviour. But, I am not able to understand why the default strings are being picked up when I select en_US as my device language.

Is it that en_US is the default language for android and whenever en_US is selected as device's language, it picks up the default strings if en_US is not provided separately?

Comment: It seems to be still happening. I thought it is specific to en_CA. It seems like a platform bug. Did you by any chance open a bug with Android? See our discussion here: [Localization for Canada defaults to UK; should default to US](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45511769/1306419)

Comment: I've created a bug report here: issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534. Feel free to suggest changes to improve it, or comment / star it so that it could be looked at. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. After opening a bug report on Google [Incorrect resource resolution strategy above Android N, defaulting to en_GB and not default strings.xml](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534), they mentioned that this in the intended behaviour for Android N above. I'm quoting their reply here:

> Starting in N, all English locales (except for US and US territories like Puerto Rico and American Samoa) fall back to some International English variant if such a locale is available.
>
> So for en-CA, we would try these locales first, before falling back on en-GB (which is considered a representative of International English if there is no better International English locale): en-rCA (Canadian English), b+en+001 (International English), en (English).
> If you don't want en-GB strings to be picked up for en-CA, you should put resources in one of those three directories, as they would be considered a better match for en-CA.

So, it turns our `en_UK` is considered "a representative of International English". The strings will fall back to "International English" or its representative before `en`.

Comment: Oh, I spent so much time before I found this post ( The same not for English only, but for Spanish as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544679/android-wrong-locale-resolution-for-es-ec-language