# Localization for Canada defaults to UK; should default to US

Tags: android, string, localization

I'm working on an application that has localized strings for the UK, specified in `res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml`. My default string implementations, for the US, are in `res/values/strings.xml`.

Now, I'm adding additional localizations for Canada in `res/values-en-rCA/strings.xml`. I would **like** the application to behave as follows: If a user's device is localized to Canada (or their language is set to `English(Canada)` or `French(Canada)`), check if we have a string in `en-rCA`, and if not, fallback to the string in my default `strings.xml` file. **However,** my application currently fallbacks to strings from `en-rGB` when the device is set to a Canadian locale and the string is not found in `en-rCA`. Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How can I configure my app such that a device with a Canadian locale searches for a string in `en-rCA` and then, if it cannot find it, defaults to the string in my default `values` folder *rather* than `en-rGB`?
2. How can I ensure that a device whose language is set to `French (Canada)` defaults to `en-rCA` rather than my default `values`, as it currently does?

I would be happy to provide an example if it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Maybe there is a bug with changes made in Android N https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html. On older API's it works fine but the new ones like 7.1.1, it is behaving the same way as you mentioned above. Maybe we should open a bug report?

Comment: Check [Android 7.0 Nougat picks up default strings when device language is en_US](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40906548/1306419) question which raised similar concern with other English locales.

Comment: I've created a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534. Feel free to suggest changes to improve it or comment / star it so that it could be looked at. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Shobhit. I starred the report. I'm also noticing the same issue when I view our Play Store listing with English (Canada) selected as my default language: our UK-specific resources (screenshots and copy) are showing up instead of our defaults. That confirms that this is a system-wide issue.

Comment: Interesting! Can you please add this as a comment on the issue as well. This might help them debug it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finale Update:**

After opening a bug report on Google [Incorrect resource resolution strategy above Android N, defaulting to en_GB and not default strings.xml](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534), they mentioned that this in the intended behaviour for Android N above. `en_UK` is considered "a representative of International English". The strings will fall back to "International English" strings or its representative before going to default `en` strings. I'm quoting their reply here:

> Starting in N, all English locales (except for US and US territories like Puerto Rico and American Samoa) fall back to some International English variant if such a locale is available.
>
> So for en-CA, we would try these locales first, before falling back on en-GB (which is considered a representative of International English if there is no better International English locale): en-rCA (Canadian English), b+en+001 (International English), en (English).
>   If you don't want en-GB strings to be picked up for en-CA, you should put resources in one of those three directories, as they would be considered a better match for en-CA.

---

**Update 1:**

It seems this is not just limited to `en_CA`. There is another similar question for other English locales : [Android 7.0 Nougat picks up default strings when device language is en_US](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40906548/1306419). Looks like a platform bug at this stage.

---

**Original Answer:**

Not sure if its a bug or a feature. From API level 24 (Android 7.0), they've updated how Android resolves strings as mentioned [Improvements to Resource-Resolution Strategy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html#postN)
. Taking an example from the documentation below:

*Before Android 7.0:*

Lets say if the user has settings of `fr_CH` and following are the resources available in the app i.e `de_DE`, `es_ES`, `fr_FR`, `it_IT`. For older API's before Android 7.0, Android tried to find an exact match and if an exact match isn't found it defaults to the `values/strings.xml`, i.e `en`. So for `en_CA` case, if a string is not found in `res/values-en-rCA/strings.xml`, we can expect it to default to `en`.
[image: Table 1. Resource resolution without an exact locale match.]

*After Android 7.0*

However now in Android 7.0 and above, for the situation of `fr_CH`, it will fall back to the **closest** parent dialect i.e `fr_FR`.
[image: Table 2. An improved resolution strategy for when there is no exact locale match.]

Applying the same logic to the situation of `en_CA` and `en_GB` present in the app, I'm thinking that Android thinks that `en_GB` is the **closest dialect** to `en_CA` and is falling back to it instead of the default `en` first. I am facing the issue in my app and that's the only plausible explanation I can come up with of why this issue happens only on newer API versions and not on the ones before Android N.

Answer (score 2):

1. Should happen automatically, without you doing anything. If you have `values/strings.xml`, `values-en-rGB/strings.xml` and `values-en-rCA/strings.xml` with the GB and CA versions containing only those strings that differ from the baseline (`values/strings.xml`) and if the user has his locale as en-CA, the system will load strings from `values-en-rCA/strings.xml` if not found, it'll fall back to `values/strings.xml`, the GB version wouldn't come in the picture.
2. For this you'll have to locally change your app locale. Basically you get the current locale, if it is fr-CA, you manually set the locale to en-CA

   ```
   Locale enCALocale = new Locale("en", "CA"); 
   Locale.setDefault(enCALocale);
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.locale = enCALocale;
   getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   ```

---

Update

As Shobhit mentioned, starting Android N, you can now have a list of locales selected in the setting and you can decide their priority:

[image]

In the above case the system will try and look for `en-rCA/strings`, if not found it'll look into `en-rGB/strings` instead of baseline, something that happened before N.

Comment: Your answer to #2 was very helpful - thanks! As for #1, I understand that this is the expected behavior, and that is indeed the way my app is setup. Still, I'm finding that a device with a Canadian locale falls back to strings from `values-en-rGB`, and am wondering if anyone knows why this is happening. If I set the device to any language other than `English (Canada)`, it falls back to my defaults as expected. Seems like there's something odd about Canadian English. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I only have English (Canada) and English (United States) in my language preferences. Even then the issue happens.

Comment: Same here, @Shobhit. Hard to tell whether it's a bug or an intentional feature. If it's a feature, it seems there should be a way to manually override and insist that it falls back to US rather than UK. Maybe we should file a bug report.

Comment: @user5194377 I think we should. The dirty temporary solution is to have all the `en_GB` strings in `en_CA` strings.xml as well.