# Android drawable is picked from drawable-en-rCA when locale is en_IN

Tags: android, localization, locale, drawable, android-resources

I have an image in folder drawable-en-rCA. I do not have any folder like drawable-en-rIN, or drawable-in. When I change my app locale to en_IN, drawable is picked-up from drawable-en-rCA whereas it is expected to take from default drawable folder as there are no drawables present specific for en_IN.

Can somebody help me to understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing this issue on device running Android N or above, I think your issue might be related to the findings mentioned on this answer: [Localization for Canada defaults to UK; should default to US](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512903/1306419). Google released a documentation on the [Improvements to Resource-Resolution Strategy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html#postN) post Android N. There was also a bug report [Incorrect resource resolution strategy above Android N, defaulting to en_GB and not default strings.xml](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534)  for the issue but it turns out it is not a bug but a feature. Here is their response:

> **Starting in Android N, all English locales (except for US and US territories like Puerto Rico and American Samoa) fall back to some International English variant if such a locale is available.**
>
> So for en-CA, we would try these locales first, before falling back on en-GB (which is considered a representative of International English if there is no better International English locale): en-rCA (Canadian English), b+en+001 (International English), en (English). If you don't want en-GB strings to be picked up for en-CA, you should put resources in one of those three directories, as they would be considered a better match for en-CA.

For your case, based on these (specially the new Resource-Resolution Strategy document), it seems that when you select `en_IN`, if any resource is not present in `drawable-en-rIN`, then it looks for the closest international english directory, which in your case in `drawable-en-rCA`. If its not present there, only then it default to the default drawable folder.

Hope it helps.