# en-rZA strings file in my app is setting a string for the en-UK locale

Tags: android, string, locale, translation, region

I recently added an `en-rZA`, `zu` and `xh` strings file to my Android application, for users from South Africa.

Each of these files contain a single translation.

This translation seems to work as expected when I am running my application on an emulator (I am from the UK, therefore I see default string) but users reported that when using the application on non-emulated devices, they are seeing the South African translation.

When debugging, I noticed that this is specifically caused by the `en-rZA` strings file, and the `zu` and `xh` strings files translate as and when expected (I changed the value in each and re-ran the app to determine where the issue was coming from).

My devices locale shows up in the debugger as en_UK, and then proceeds to show the `en-rZA` translation.

A workaround I am currently using is to introduce an `en_rGB` strings file with the correct translation, but it doesn't make sense to me that I should need to do this.

What is causing this mis-translation, am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected (although surprising) behaviour starting with Android N according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512903/766024 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64429534?pli=1

The solution is to duplicate `values/strings.xml` in `values-en/strings.xml` or `values-b+en+001/strings.xml`