# Android wrong locale resolution for ES-EC language

Tags: android, localization

I have the next localization in my app:

values
values-es
values-es-rMX

When I have locale of the device set to es_EC (Ecuador), I see strings from MX folder!
But accordingly to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support) tutorial, I should see strings from base ES folder (actually, this is the goal).

Why is it happening and how can I get correct app behavior?
I'm using an emulator with API level 28.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer is on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906548/android-7-0-nougat-picks-up-default-strings-when-device-language-is-en-us), the reason is the same, this is intended behavior for Android system.